# If app disconnect internet, how to get device token(APNS) again?

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications, appdelegate, devicetoken

I am implement ios APNS , I write the code in AppDelegate.m, and pass the device token to my view controller( Use NSUserDefaults) .

Then  there are a button in view controller, when user click the button , it will send device token to my server.

But the question is coming. If the user is not connect Internet, the button action will detect the device token is null or not.

When the device token is null, the app have to detected network and request device token.

But the device token is wrote in AppDelegate.m, how to implement registered device token in the class alone?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the resolve.

Setting the code in applicationDidBecomeActive.

Answer (score 1):

I think every time your app launch , you should register to get the device token and send to your server, if network is disconnected, you should do above when the network is access.
(if no network, it is no use for you to get the token, because you can not send it to your sever, by the way , system will store the device token and you may get the device token immediately after you register)

Comment: I wish send to my server in view controller. 
Because I have other parameter selected from user. 
So I don't want send the device token to my server when app lunch. 
I wish device token with other parameter send to sever once time in my view controller.

Comment: ok, but i think you should send the device token to your server as soon as possible.

Comment: But I don't know how to registered to device token not in app launch.
I don't know how to implement registered device token in other class. 
I want to registered device token again in view controller. Have anyone know ? thank you

Comment: `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:(UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge | UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound | UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert)];` after you get the device token , you can post a notification or something else...

Comment: Hi yuanrui, your method is implement in AppDelegat, It is can't implement in viewconroller button action. I fell it would be implement some delegate in view controller. thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Device Token will not get generate when internet is offline. To generate device token device must required internet connection.